# I cannot get text With jsoup : element.text()

Tags: java, html, jsoup, google-translate

I cannot get text With Jsoup :  `element.text()`
It doesn't show me anything, someone help me please.

```
 org.jsoup.nodes.Document d = Jsoup.connect("https://translate.google.com/#en/ar/scraping").get();
 org.jsoup.nodes.Element element = d.getElementById("result_box");
 out.print(element.text());
```

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML you are working with? I'm unable to connect to that url via Jsoup.

Answer (score 0):

When you view the static page source here: https://translate.google.com/#en/ar/scraping you'll see that it contains this:

```
<span id="result_box" class="short_text"></span>
```

But on loading the page in your browser you'll see that element is changed to:

```
<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="ar">
    <span class="">...</span>
</span>
```

So, the *content* of the `result_box` span is populated dynamically.

This means that it cannot be scraped by JSoup.

To read dynamic content you'll need to use a webdriver such as [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp).